# Can f(n) belong to both o(g(n)) and big omega(g(n))?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

I have a small query.
Can `f(n)` belong to both `o(g(n))` *and* `big omega(g(n))`?
I'm not able to figure it out. Can someone explain me please?

Comment: Isn't this better asked on http://cs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

No it can't. Since `o(g(n))` means time complexity *strictly* less than `g(n)` and `ω(g(n))` *strictly* greater.

Answer (score 2):

New answer (for editted question):

**No**, it cannot. 
**Formal proof**, based on [set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) and the fact that `o(g(n))` and `Ω(g(n))` are sets of functions:

```
o(g(n)) = O(g(n)) \ Θ(g(n))
Θ(g(n)) = Ω(g(n)) ∩ O(g(n))

o(g(n)) ∩ Ω(g(n)) = { O(g(n)) \ Θ(g(n)) } ∩ Ω(g(n))  
                  = { O(g(n)) ∩ Ω(g(n)) } \ Θ(g(n)) [see appendix 1]
                  = Θ(g(n)) \ Θ(g(n)) = {}
```

Since `o(g(n)) ∩ Ω(g(n))` is an empty set, there is no function `f(n)` that belongs to the intersection, thus no function belongs to both sets.

**QED**

Appendix 1:

Let's make sure we understand this equality:

> (1) = { O(g(n)) \ Θ(g(n)) } ∩ Ω(g(n))  = { O(g(n)) ∩ Ω(g(n)) } \
>   Θ(g(n)) = (2)

- If x is not in O(g(n)) - it is not in (1), and also not in (2),
  regardless of appearing in the other sets.
- if x is in O(g(n)) and in Θ(g(n)), it is not in (1) and also not in
  (2), regardless of appearing in Ω(g(n))
- if x is in O(g(n)), not in  Θ(g(n)) and yes in Ω(g(n)), it is both in (1) and in (2)
- if x is in O(g(n)), not in  Θ(g(n)) and not in Ω(g(n)), it is not in (1) and also not in (2)

Since this concludes all possibilities, and we found that in all of them, x is in (1) if and only if it is also in (2), the equation is true.

---

**Old answer** (for original question, asking about small omega):

**No**, it cannot. 
**Formal proof**, based on [set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) and the fact that `o(g(n))` and `ω(g(n))` are sets of functions:

```
o(g(n)) = O(g(n)) \ Θ(g(n))
omega(g(n)) = Ω(g(n)) \ Θ(g(n))

o(g(n)) ∩ ω(g(n)) = { O(g(n)) \ Θ(g(n)) } ∩ { Ω(g(n)) \ Θ(g(n)) } 
                  = { Ω(g(n)) ∩ O(g(n)) } \ Θ(g(n)) 
                  = Θ(g(n)) \ Θ(g(n))
                  = {}
```

Since `o(g(n)) ∩ ω(g(n))` is an empty set, there is no function `f(n)` that belongs to the intersection, thus no function belongs to both sets.

**QED**

Comment: "`o(g(n)) = O(g(n)) \ Theta(g(n))`" Hm, the quantifiers make the situation a bit more complicated than that. It's fair to say that it's a subset though.

Comment: Hello amit, thank you so much but here the omega is big omega not small omega

Comment: @Aashi and what about `o` - is it big O or small o?

Answer (score 2):

We can use the definitions of o(n) and Omega(n):
We assume that there is a function g with the following properties: g(n) = o(f(n)) and g(n) = Omega(f(n)).

If g(n) = o(f(n)) then for every positive constant c1: 0 <= g(n) < c1 * f(n). (1)

If g(n) = Omega(f(n)) then there is a positive constant c2 for which 0 <= c2 * f(n) <= g(n).

Statement (1) is also true for c1 = c2, which means that
0 <= g(n) < c2 * f(n) and 0 <= c2 * f(n) <= g(n).

Now we have g(n) < c2 * f(n) and g(n) >= c2 * f(n), which is impossible, so our initial assumption is false. So, there is no such function g, and the intersection of o(f(n)) and Omega(f(n)) is the empty set.